# Set coordinates of xarray DataArray dimension

Tags: python-xarray

I like to concat/stack different DataArrays into a new one, with certain coordinates at the concat dimension:

```py
x1 = xr.DataArray(np.arange(0,3)[...,np.newaxis], coords=[('b', np.arange(3,6)),('a', [10])]).squeeze()
x2 = xr.DataArray(np.arange(1,4)[...,np.newaxis], coords=[('b', np.arange(3,6)),('a', [10])]).squeeze()

xc = xr.concat([x1,x2], dim='new')
```

```
<xarray.DataArray (new: 2, b: 3)>
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3]])
Coordinates:
  * b        (b) int64 3 4 5
    a        int64 10
Dimensions without coordinates: new
```

How can I set the coordinates of dimension with the concat function 'new'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dim` argument in the `concat` function can take a DataArray or pandas.Index in addition to the name of the concat dimension:

```
xc = xr.concat([x1,x2], dim=xr.DataArray(['a', 'b'], dims='new', name='new'))
```

More detail in the `xarray.concat` documentation: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html#xarray.concat

Answer (score 1):

Setting the coordinates can be done via:

```
xc['new'] = ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: This needs two line of codes, can it be done in one?

Comment: Sometimes the solution with more lines of code is easier to read. I am much more likely to remember this solution than the more complex one-liner.